# How can I restore my Lenovo T500 to Switchable Graphics without being able to see the screen?

Tags: thinkpad, cmos

I changed my Lenovo T500 from 'Switchable Graphics' to 'Discrete Graphics' in the BIOS.

Now I don't get any display out on the internal LCD, or an external VGA monitor. Not even the POST screen.

How can I revert to Switchable Graphics or Internal Graphics mode?

Even if somebody could just give me BIOS photos I might be able to step through it blind ...

Answer (score 2):

Try F1 to enter the BIOS, F9 to load defaults, F10 to save and exit.  Both F9 and F10 will give you a yes/no prompt, but unfortunately I don't know if they default to 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: You can always press 'Y' key to make it 'yes', no matter the default is 'yes' or 'no'